# I cannot maintain Bluetooth connection between old MacBook and new iPhone, because standard has changed so much in 8 years?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, bluetooth

I have a 2012 MacBook running Catalina and an iPhone 12. MacBook requesting to connect never works. iPhone making the request works. But, the MB then disconnects after a several seconds or minutes. Some Bluetooth speakers can connect and be used by both with no problems. An Apple Watch connects to the iPhone but the MB does not see it.

So, there is nothing I can do to reliably connect the new iPhone to the old MB? The standards have changed too much?

Comment: I had a 15 inch 2015 MBP until recently and sync-ing wirelessly was *always* problematic. But now with my new 16 inch MBP it is (almost) flawless in its ability to sync wirelessly. New standards are a definite possibility, and I would think so is more robust, reliable and better engineered systems as another explanation.

Comment: Older Apple devices had a pretty small Bluetooth range. I got a BT dongle for my 2007 mini. That's helped considerably. Be certain to check for Apple compatibility before buying.

Comment: Just noting 8 years is A LOT of time in the computer world with respect to Moore's Law

Answer (score 0):

Like Wayfanning Stranger said in comments, I'm going to try a (usb to bluetooth) extender. I had really given-up. I am sure I'll get the correct extender to work. What a break through. Thanks so much.